# How to change hover color on checkout country selection in WooCommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, css-selectors, wordpress-theming

Working on one small project, and have a little issue that dont know how to resolve. On my [dev site link](https://naturallybirthed.com/product/50-50-bar-soap/?add-to-cart=432) when add some product to cart and I proceed to checkout, in the Country select field, every country have some green color on hover that I want to change.

I found this CSS for that selector:

```
.select2-drop.select2-drop-active
```

But whatever I change, dont seems to take effect.

This is what I got visually:

[image]

Maybe i see in wrong CSS class I dont know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** The responsible CSS rule when hovering a selected values is:

```css
.woocommerce .select2-results li.select2-highlighted, 
.woocommerce-page .select2-results li.select2-highlighted {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

You should might be obliged *(or not)* to add **`!important`** to overwrite existing rules…

Comment: Have in my question. Have that "my dev site" is linked.

Comment: No problem mate. Thanks once again. :)